# InfoPath forms and some services do not work after database restoration!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, database, content-database

Last they some of my SharePoint server databases stuck in restoring state. After I solved those databases issue. Now some of my SharePoint features do not work. For example Infopath forms can not be loaded and the error below is raised:

> The form cannot be rendered. This may be due to a misconfiguration of
>   the Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service. For more information,
>   contact your server administrator.

And also some of service application raise error. For example the Secure Store Service can not be configured and the error below is raised:

> Cannot complete this action as the Secure Store Shared Service is not
>   responding. Please contact your administrator.

**How can I resolve this issue that is related to SharePoint server databases?**

Comment: I guess you have tried to reboot the SharePoint server after the restore has finished?

Comment: Yes, I also reboot the server after restoration was completed.Why?

Comment: What do you mean why? Because it is an easy and effective way to get all SharePoint services restarted. Your errors are generic so it could very well be a stuck services that needed to be restarted. But a plain reboot obviously was not enough.

Comment: You are right, but I checked the services and all of them are started. Do you know what are the services related to this issue to check?

Comment: Not really, but there are two specific services mentioned in your error messages above, try stopping and the start them again. But I am no expert on neither of these two services unfortunately